# How to disable mouse click on old dates in Oracle Apex Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, calendar, oracle-apex-5.1

I have one Oracle Apex calendar in my scheduler application . With create link and view/edit link enabled to different pages in application.

Is there any way to disable click on old dates from today.

I have tried css ways , but its not working .

```
td .fc-day.ui-widget-content.fc-past{  
   pointer-events:none !important;
   background-color: gray;
}
```

Above code only changes the color.

Please help .

Is there any way by using jquery or javascript to disable these old dates ??

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through details about full calendar i found out the solution .
I had to put the below code in 'JavaScript Initialization Code' section  of Apex calendar attributes .

```
function (pOptions) {
    pOptions.weekNumberCalculation= 'ISO';
    pOptions.weekNumbers = true; 
    pOptions.weekNumberTitle = "W";
    pOptions.selectAllow = function (info) {
        if (info.start.isBefore(moment().add(-1, 'days')))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    return pOptions;
}
```